# If all words have the same frequency, is the generated Huffman tree a balanced binary tree?

Tags: machine-learning, information-theory, huffman-coding

If all words have the same frequency, is the generated Huffman tree a balanced binary tree? At the same time, is the generated Huffman tree a complete binary tree?

Comment: What do you think? Have you tried running the algorithm in this case and seeing what you get?

Comment: Yes, I have tried running it in some cases and found it is not only a balanced binary tree, but also a complete binary tree. But is there a formal proof on it?

Comment: It should be possible to trace the entire execution of the algorithm, and to show that it results in a complete binary tree, at least when $n$ is a power of 2. You can start with this case. Another option is showing that every minimum redundancy code must correspond to a complete binary tree. Since Huffman's algorithm produced such a code, this would complete the proof.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As we know, the Huffman's algorithm produces a minimum redundancy code, but it doesn't necessarily correspond to a complete binary tree. So I think the second solution is infeasible. For the first solution, you may be confused with a complete binary tree and a full binary tree, when $n$ is a power of 2, it must be a full binary tree, then it is also surely a complete binary tree.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways to analyze what happens when the distribution is uniform over $n = 2^m$ many codewords. The situation for other values of $n$ is more complicated, but similar techniques might work.

**Minimum redundancy codes**

Suppose that $w_1,\ldots,w_n$ is a prefix code. According to Kraft's inequality,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n 2^{-|w_i|} \leq 1.
$$
Since $x \mapsto 2^{-x}$ is strictly convex,
$$
\frac{1}{n} \geq \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n 2^{-|w_i|} \geq 2^{-\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n |w_i|},
$$
with equality only if all $|w_i|$ are equal. Taking the base 2 logarithm, this shows that
$$
\log_2 n \leq \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n |w_i|,
$$
with equality only if all $|w_i|$ are equal to $\log_2 n$. In particular, in any minimum redundancy code, all codewords have length $\log_2 n$, and so the coding tree is a complete binary tree.

**Analyzing Huffman's algorithm**

Huffman's algorithm starts with the $n$ original codewords, each of weight $1/n$. In the first $n/2$ steps, the original codewords are paired up to $n/2$ many codewords of weight $2/n$. In the following $n/4$ steps, the new codewords are paired up to $n/4$ many codewords of weight $4/n$, and so on. Eventually, we get a coding tree which is a complete binary tree.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have read the Kraft's inequality part of Information Theory, and known the concrete proof of $n=2^m$ case before. But how to extend the proof to other cases? For example, for $n=3^m$, I'm still a little confused.

Comment: You’ll have to do some of the work on your own.

Comment: OK, thank you, and I'll have a try.